# How to remove default fields in kibana 5.3

Tags: elastic-stack, kibana-5

I have setup ELK stack 5.3. Now kibana is messed up with a lot of values under "**Available Fields**". How to remove these unwanted fields?

Also, I need to remove some built in fields like "beat.hostname","beat.name","beat.version",etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Available Fields column just represents all the fields in your visible result set. (First 500 results by default.) If you want to get rid of some fields you have to adjust your Logstash / Ingest-Node settings, to get rid of the field altogether.

As for removing fields, you can use any filter to remove them.

Example:

```
mutate {
  remove_field => ["%{beat}"] # delete the entire Beat field
}

mutate {
  remove_field => ["%{[beat][hostname]}"] # delete a nested field
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have hidden unwanted fields by adding them in Management > Kibana > Indices > Source Filters.